# How can I create half Circular Chart with arrow pointing at current value - React Native

Tags: react-native, charts, geometry, progress-bar, pie-chart

I need to create a chart like that one in image attached. The only one problem I have is with this arrow that is pointing at certain value. I have no idea how can i create it. From all of the libraries I couldn't find anything suitable. Can anyone help me with the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an example, you can take this library https://github.com/ahernandez9/react-native-arc-progress-bar

It is based on reanimated. It is not 100% what you need but you can fork it and do some additions.

[image]